# Open big files with SSZipArchive leads to crash

Tags: ios, crash, unzip, openurl, ssziparchive

My app is crashing when I'm opening a .zip file and unzipping it with SSZipArchive. I think this happens due to memory pressure because it is not crashing when monitored by Instruments or executed by the debugger. Is there a chance to "slowly" unzip it or unzip it step for step to prevent those crashes (I get those on Iphone 4s and Iphone 6).

My .zip file has about 20MB and contains 1900 images.

Comment: Which version/commit of SSZipArchive are you using? I remember there is a commit in the SSZipArchive repo fixed the memory pressure bug.

Comment: I'm not really sure about this but it has to be a version that has been released before July 2015. Do you know when this was fixed?

Comment: How did you import the SSZipArchive library? Is it by using cocoapods? If so you may check your Podfile. I think [this pull request](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/pull/213) might mitigate the memory issue problem which is on Nov of 2015.

Comment: I suggest trying out different tag version (e.g. 1.1, 1.0.1 and 0.4.0) to see if that's the case.

Comment: I imported it without cocoapods. I will try the newest version and let you know if it works, thx ;)

Comment: Please do try cocoapods as it brings importing very convenient.